# Compiling RTEMS RTOS on Ubuntu (Not installing it) and using its Linker Script to run simple c programs

Tags: c, compilation, ubuntu-14.04, building, rtems

As a part of my project, i need to compile RTEMS on ubuntu and need to access its linker script to run simple C programs.

Majorly, i need help on the following formidable first part:
PART 1. Compiling Rtems on Ubuntu (not installing Rtems). How can i compile an Operating System without installing it?

Where do i begin?
i have tried searching about this in a lot of places but clueless.

Thing/s i have tried:

1.running `make` in the rtems-4.6.2 directory

2.Googling extensively- everything keeps leading me to downloading rtems in a cross development environment.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. many thanks.

Comment: I found soemthing [HERE](http://linux.programdevelop.com/2323080/) it is old, but you can start from there, but sou should [read this](https://ftp.rtems.org/pub/rtems/people/chrisj/source-builder/source-builder.html) also.

Comment: https://learnsom2day.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/getting-started-with-rtems-hello-word/